# Epson ESCPOS thermal print with special Danish character

Tags: python, epson, pos, escpos, codepage-437

I am using [python-escpos](https://pypi.org/project/python-escpos/#description) version 2.2.0 for printing text on my Epson TM-T88V thermal receipt printer. My printer is configured:

1. Using international character set called "DENMARK II"
2. Using code page WPC1252

I have troubles in printing the extended Danish character æ, ø and å. I have verfied that they exists in WPC1252. Below is my code python code

```
from escpos import printer

printer_ipAddress = "192.168.0.200"
p = printer.Network(printer_ipAddress)
p.set(align = 'LEFT', width = 2, height = 2)
text = 'æ,ø,å'
p.text(text)
p.cut()
```

When I execute above code I get some strange looking character output instead of the Danish character æ, ø and å.

Comment: Perhaps the CodePage settings and the Encoding process are inconsistent. It seems that unicode is output as it is if nothing is set. Please try inserting `p.charcode('WPC1252')` before `p.set(...)`. However, although the encoding seems to be done correctly, the codepage setting may have the wrong value of Cyrillic #2.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @kunif the codepage was set inconsistently. I added

```
p.codepage = 'CP858'
```

before the `p.set` command and the issue was solved.